# Use table functions and valued functions SQL in .net core 3 web api

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a database that contains many table and values functions , is there a method to call these functions dynamically. I use .net core 3 web api.
any help please

Answer (score 0):

I will do it using Dapper and then call funtions using SP or select statement in a way you want

Below is example of using Dapper & Select statement to get data from API

```
    //for EF
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    //For  Dapper
    private readonly SqlConnectionConfiguration _configuration;


    public NewsController(ApplicationDbContext db, SqlConnectionConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _db = db;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {

            //fetch data using EF
            // return Json(new { data = await _db.News.OrderByDescending(x => x.NewsDate).ToListAsync() });

            //Fetch data using Dapper
            IEnumerable<News> newslist;
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration.Value))
            {
                string query = "select * FROM News";

                conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    newslist = await conn.QueryAsync<News>(query, commandType: CommandType.Text);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }

            }

            return Json(new { data = newslist });


        }
```

Rest  you can make change to below code to make it work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, currently I use pattern repository and unitofwork, can I use this method with dbContext?

Comment: @Anas, I am myself new to asp.net core and prefer to use Dapper for complex SQL queries and stored procedure and some function which run as part of sql statement. I have modified solution you can see i have properties defined for both EF & Dapper.. and can use both in my API controller.. Hope this will help.. In case you dont have have Dapper then you have to install.

Comment: @Anas, if question has helped you then mark it as correct

Comment: The question is not clear but your answer does not seem to be helping. Edit it according to the user comments/feedback

Comment: @efekctive, as you mentioned his question was not clear, my replay was based on assumption which was correct, but it seems user wants complete solution from us which. my solution seems to have serverd his purpose or atleast helped him...

Comment: Thank you @student,  it doesn't solve the problem, I don't want to use separate connection, i want to use my dbContext